# couchdb doesn't like accented characters in a json doc

Tags: couchdb

The following JSON object causes a CouchDB insert (POST)
to fail with "invalid JSON" message
The accent É here *is* UTF8

```
  var o = JSON.stringify({"Éditeur": 123});

  var httpOpts = {
      hostname: "localhost",
      port: 5984,
      path: '/theDb',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Content-Length': o.length}
     }

    var req = http.request(httpOpts, function(res) {
      console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
      console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
      res.setEncoding('utf8');
      res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
      });
    });

    req.write(o)
    req.end()
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it'S not couchDB's fault, 
Content-Length needs to be given the byte count,
not character count, which is what JavaScript's string.length gives you,

using the function below to count the bytes solves the problem

function byteCount(s) {
    return encodeURI(s).split(/%..|./).length - 1;
}